# android: not able to cancel LED notification

Tags: android, notifications, led

I can't figure out how to cancel an LED `notification` which was set previously. First I call some init:

```
private void initNoti() {

    mNoti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Main Gate")
        .setContentText(s_clUnregistered)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nocon)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setShowWhen(false)
        .setContentIntent(notiPendingIntent)
        .build();

    startForeground(noti_id, mNoti);
}
```

After it, I modificate it while running:

```
private void setNoti(String msg) {
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(s_mgStrin g);
    mBuilder.setContentText(s_clUnregistered);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nocon);
    mBuilder.setShowWhen(false);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notiPendingIntent);
    mNotifyManager.notify(noti_id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

...and set some LED notification:

```
private void setLedNoti() {

    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setLights(0xffff0000, 300, 100);
    mNotifyManager.notify(noti_id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This all happens within a service.
`mNoti`, `mBuilder`, `mNotifyManager` are class variables.

But any time, I want to cancel the LED `notification`. Therefore I call the `mNotifyManager.cancel(noti_id);` Unfortunately, the LED `notifciation` remains flashing. It cannot be cancelled. Does anybody have any idea how to realize that?

Comment: first try to `stopForeground` before cancel your `Notification` may help you

Comment: I did `stopForeground(true);
   mNotifyManager.cancel(noti_id);` but the notification LED was still flashing. Nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: One more idea may be works...try instead of stopForeground call...
mNotificationManager.cancel(noti_id);
startForeground(noti_id,null); may be work...